# CodeMirror with Tern - Custom "Types" with Javascript Intellisense

Tags: javascript, codemirror, tern

I am using `tern` to give some enhanced intellisense to a window that runs with `CodeMirror`, and it works fine, but I am having an issue where I would like to add some custom "`types`", so to speak, so that there can be icons next to them in the drop down. I have narrowed the code down a bit...

In the `.json` definition files, types seem to be declared using the `!type` directive, like this;

```
  "Infinity": {
    "!type": "number",
    "!url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity",
    "!doc": "A numeric value representing infinity."
  },
  "undefined": {
    "!type": "?",
    "!url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined",
    "!doc": "The value undefined."
  }
```

These correspond a bit with the `CSS`, like this.

```
.CodeMirror-Tern-completion-object:before {
    content: "O";
    background: #77c;
}
.CodeMirror-Tern-completion-fn:before {
    content: "F";
    background: #7c7;
}
.CodeMirror-Tern-completion-array:before {
    content: "A";
    background: #c66;
}
.CodeMirror-Tern-completion-number:before {
    content: "1";
    background: #999;
}
```

Alright, that's all fine and good. I can style those, no problem. But I want to add some of my own, and am having a heck of a hard time doing that. For instance, if I just do ...

```
  "Character": {
    "!type": "entity",
    "!url": "some-url",
    "!doc": "This is a character entity."
  },
  "User": {
    "!type": "user",
    "!url": "some-url-again",
    "!doc": "This is a user entity."
  }
```

It just kind of causes the whole thing to not work; Like `tern` just kind of says `nope nope nope` and does nothing. I have been trying for hours, and have really dug through the source code, but cannot really find a way to just make up my own types. I want to simply give the users of this specific code editor (which won't be 'exactly' javascript, it'll be javascript, but with some dumbed-down literals, since they are not coders) some simple flags to make it easier on them.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you for your time.

## Update

As a user requested, I am posting more code to try and get more help. This is what I want; I have a `.json` file that defines the layout of an object. The object will mirror an actual C# object/database object. (That part isn't important, just know that I have a specific model)

I am also using the default tern `ecma5.json` and `jquery.json` def files. They are found here;

https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/defs/ecma5.json
https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/defs/jquery.json

So when the user hits `CTRL+SPACE` and sees `CHARACTER`, I want it to have a type of [`CHARACTER`] next to it. So I thought the first step was to specify character as the type.

### `character.json`

```
"character": {
    "!type": "Character",
    "!doc": "Represents the character model.",
    "Coefficients":{
        "!doc": "The coefficients that govern many of the calculative formulas"
    }
}
```

What happened is the following screen.

[image: ctrl+space with character as defined type]

Now I tried to trace this down, I discovered a function called `typeToIcon` in the `addons/tern.js` (not the actual tern files, the addon file that plugs into codemirror)

```
function typeToIcon(type) {
    var suffix;

    if (type == "?") suffix = "unknown";
    else if (
        type == "number"        || 
        type == "string"        || 
        type == "bool"          
    ) suffix = type;

    else if (/^fn\(/.test(type)) suffix = "fn";
    else if (/^\[/.test(type)) suffix = "array";
    else suffix = "object";

    return cls + "completion " + cls + "completion-" + suffix;
}
```

So I though `AHA! This is it!!`, so I figured I could add my type here.

I added `console.log(type);` to the function to see what the output was like. This never fired though, even when I hit `CTRL+SPACE`, I never saw a console output, so it tells me that this code was not reached. I had to go further back.

I hunted down a function called `TypeParser` in `def.js`, part of the actual tern download.

```
  var TypeParser = exports.TypeParser = function (spec, start, base, forceNew) {
    this.pos = start || 0;
    this.spec = spec;
    this.base = base;
    this.forceNew = forceNew;
  };
```

putting a console log here gave me some results, and they looked like many of the types that were available, and that were defined in `jquery.json` and `ecma5.json`.

This is as far as I have gotten, I have absolutely no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Just bump-ing this, wondering how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The styling is handled by the CodeMirror Tern plugin, which only recognizes primitive JS types. When defining a JSON definition file, you can't just use random strings as types—you have to use names that either refer to actual variables in the JS environment, or primitive types (`string`, `number`, etc).

Comment: There is no possible way to append this and make it believe there are other primitive types?

Comment: I know this seems absurd, and please understand I am not wanting to actually make new types. I am making this "editor" for a website that needs some lightweight scripting, and the staff members that will use it do not know how to program. They are just not those kind of people. I am using every tool I can to make the scripting "interface" as friendly to them as possible so that they are less confused. Being able to label things like `[CHARACTER]`, `[ACTION]`, etc, would greatly ease the stress they are suffering.

Comment: They see "Object" "Function" etc and are just confused. Sometimes I can coach them through it, but the user is always the most important part of the end product.

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is too specific and couldn't be provided by CodeMirror, there's always a way out.
What I understood from the code you provided is that, you could just Identify "user","entity" and other custom dataTypes in the language mode Eg : ("javascript.js") and store their types in the local/global variable list.

And then customise hint-functions to provide similar like interface via changing Hint widget.

If you really want to implement this feature, you should better implement own module like I suggested so that complete control will be in your hand.

Comment: See that is the approach I took as well, thinking it would work. But at some point along the way, attempting to deviate from javascrpt primitives just causes the `tern` system to outright not run. I have not been able to even get an error message, a console output, anything.

Comment: Then you must be breaking the flow somewhere, you should debug that part. I feel that would be the best approach and if you provide some of the code that you tried, we would really be happy to help you.
Regards

Comment: I greatly appreciate that. I would really love some help. This is bringing me to tears out of frustration. I will try to provide more code in an hour or so. I will preface this that my knowledge of `tern` is 0. I know what I have garnered by reaming the source code, and JavaScript is already my weakest language. Please hold while I see what I can show that may demonstrate more. What kind of code would be helpful for you?

Comment: Hey @djadmin, I have added more of what I could. I am sorry if it is useless. I have no idea what I am doing. http://i.imgur.com/TyB2zXI.jpg

Comment: I cannot understand your approach, but from what I understood, you should modify the emacs.json file according to your need and then try loading the modified json with your approach.